# Kubernetes storing persistent files

Tags: kubernetes, certificate

What's the best way to store a persistent file in Kubernetes? I have a cert (.pfx) and I want to be passing to the application its path. From the looks of it it can't be stored in secrets. Was thinking about a volume but the question is how do I upload the file to it? And which type of volume to choose? Or is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's unclear from your question why you came to the conclusion that it can't be stored as a Secret. This is one of the main [use cases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-cases) for Secrets.

Step 1. Create a Secret from your file:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=myfile=/tmp/my.pfx
```

Step 2. Mount the Secret volume into a Pod:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secret-volume
      mountPath: "/etc/secret-volume"
```

Your container should see a file at `/etc/secret-volume/myfile`

Answer (score 0):

**you can copy your ".pfx" file into local directory like "/home/certs/" and than mount this directory inside to your pod,check below yaml**

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: localhostpath
    hostPath:
      path: /home/certs # path on local file system
      type: DirectoryOrCreate # create if not exist
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: localhostpath
      mountPath: "/root/certs" # path inside pod or containers
```